# Bower выдаёт ошибку git is not installed or not in the PATH, как настроить?

Tags: windows, git, gulp, bower

Сам гит интсталлировал. Bower установил и глобально и локально.

Нашёл [инструкцию](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20666989/bower-enogit-git-is-not-installed-or-not-in-the-path) тут, как менять пути какие-то, но что-то не уверен, стоит ли там что-то менять.

Answer (score 3):

При установке Git For Windows задает вот такой вопрос (привожу английскую версию, поскольку русская и без того понятна):

[image]

Вы, видимо, выбрали первый вариант - потому вам git и доступен только через Git Bash (ну, или просто что-то сбилось). Переустановите Git выбрав второй вариант - тогда git будет доступен через обычную командную строку тоже.

Также вместо переустановки можно добавить нужную папку в PATH вручную. В Windows 8.1 это делается через "Панель управления" (или ПКМ на кнопке "Пуск") - "Система" - "Дополнительные параметры системы" - вкладка "Дополнительно" (активна по умолчанию) - "Переменные среды..." (кнопка внизу).

Надо добавить папку с бинарником гита в список Path (разделитель - точка с запятой). Это должна быть либо субдиректория `bin` директории установки git (там лежат программы `bash.exe` и `git.exe`) - либо субдиректория `usr\bin` (там лежит кроме `git.exe` комплект стандартных консольных программ оболочки UNIX).

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался в чём дело. Просто вместо git использовал обычную командную строку.

Comment: Лучше бы добавил git в path.